# Host <wrong host> not allowed to connect to this MySQL server trying to deploy IIS ASP.NET website

Tags: mysql, asp.net, iis

I need some help trying to deploy an asp.net 2.0 old website.

I am running: **Window 10 version 1803, IIS version 10.0.17134.1**

Currently the server is running a wordpress site connected to MySQL (let's call it wrong-wp.com). I am trying to deploy an old legacy ASP.NET 2.0 site (let's call it right-aspnet.com), with SQL Server 2014.

First I tried to browse right-aspnet.com, but IE edge gave me this error

`Error Code: INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE`.

Chrome gave me this

`error: empty page return`.

I restarted the server, restarted my computer, nothing changed. So I added an html page, index.htm.  Both browser rendered fine, both return the page.  So I figured it is not a problem with DNS. Maybe I was wrong. When I browse the site, I realized both browsers tried to add www in front of the domain,  so I bind the www.right-aspnet.com and added onto the host file.

## That's when I get this error:

```
 Configuration Error 
 Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

 Parser Error Message: Host 'wrong-wp.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

 Source Error: 

 Line 175:    <siteMap>
 Line 176:      <providers>
 Line 177:        <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider"   type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/"/>
 Line 178:      </providers>
 Line 179:    </siteMap>

 Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727  \Config\machine.config    Line: 177
```

**Version Information:**

```
Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8922; 

ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8922
```

Any idea why it is looking into the wrong host 'wrong-wp.com' and trying to connect to MySQL?

Any help to fix this problem is greatly appreciated!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by deleting line 177 right out from the machine.config file.

```
Line 177:        <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider"   type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/"/>
```

Since it is pointing to the .net framework directory

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727  \Config\machine.config
```

I can safely assume no MySQL is going to be used for any asp.net v2.0 sites.

Answer (score 0):

Create new user with new password and grant privileges:

```
 CREATE USER 'name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'name'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'name'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, I did and I got a new error:  Authentication to host '' for user '' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user ''@'wrong-wp.com' (using password: NO).  I however got it fix though by deleting the line right out from the machine.config file.  Thanks anyway!